# java multi mapping arraylist

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, arraylist

Is it possible to map key to Multi Dimensional Array List. Some thing like following example..

```
Map<K,V>
```

Where K is key for list of alphabet and V is a multi dimensional array list or normal array list that stores list of word. Some thing like a application that reads a dictionary file. I want to see an example. Example can be anything related to Map and Multi Dimensional Array-list. **Or is there any other efficient way to implement collection?** I have never used such implementations so if there is already a thread related to mine QA please post the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always do `Map<String, <List<String>>`.  e.g.

```
Map<String, List<String>> multimap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
String key = "asdf";
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
multimap.put(key, values);
```

You can also use the `Multimap<String, String>` interface in [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) - might be a better fit for your needs.  It simplifies the coding somewhat -

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap<String, String>();
String key = "asdf";
multimap.put(key, "foo");
multimap.put(key, "bar");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Guava's Multimap's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) if you want to associate multiple values with a single key. You need [ArrayListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) for your specific case.

Example

```
ListMultimap<String, String> dict= new ArrayListMultimap<String, String>();
dict.put("key 1", "value 1");
dict.put("key 1", "value 2");
dict.put("key 2", "value 1");
```

Comment: `'ArrayListMultimap()' has private access in 'com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap'` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();` instead?

Comment: Above Guava 21 both `new ArrayListMultimap<String, String>();` and `ArrayListMultimap.create();` are deprecated. The new style is: `ListMultimap<String, Integer> result = MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build()`  enjoy :)

Comment: To be precise `ArrayListMultimap.create();` works, but in the documentation it is marked as "soon to be deprecated".

Answer (score 4):

Following  code without Google's Guava library. It is used for double value as key and sorted order

```
Map<Double,List<Object>> multiMap = new TreeMap<Double,List<Object>>();

for( int i= 0;i<15;i++)
{
    List<Object> myClassList = multiMap.get((double)i);
    if(myClassList == null)
    {
        myClassList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        multiMap.put((double) i,myClassList);
    }
    myClassList.add("Value "+ i);
}

List<Object> myClassList = multiMap.get((double)0);
if(myClassList == null)
{
    myClassList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    multiMap.put( (double) 0,myClassList);
}
myClassList.add("Value Duplicate");
for (Map.Entry entry : multiMap.entrySet()) 
{
  System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " +entry.getValue());
}
```