# How to calculate List values of a MultiMap?

Tags: java, guava

for example I am keeping Students school marks. 
So on the `MultiMap`  I have the Student Name  and Marks of all the subjects

```
e.g.  {Anne, { 54, 23, 54, 65, 76}
```

I want to generate a Map which consist of StudentName, Average marks
as in this case is `{Anne, 54.4}`

Comment: Again, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Seems like you want us to write you a complete program, line by line, because [it's another basic question about Guava's `Multimap` within few minutes authored by you](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A489818+%5Bguava%5D) and answers can be found on Wiki, in docs and in the web.

Comment: Do you want to populate a new map ?

Comment: I see a [common thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400732/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-two-mapstring-string) of questions developing here.... When you get your solution, make sure you answer your original question. ;-)

Comment: @Jonathan. Hi, Are you from SITA ?

Comment: @RaisAlam I'm afraid I don't know what that is, sorry.

Comment: @Xaerxess thanks. really appreciated your assistance. 
In here I tried transformEntries and still out of luck figuring out. This is not explained on their documentation as far as I scanned.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
for (String name : multimap.keySet())
{
     List<Integer> marks = multimap.get(name);
     int sum = 0 ;
     for (Integer num : marks )
     {
         sum += num;
     }
     double avg = (double)sum / marks.size();
     map.put(name,avg);
}
```

Comment: I cannot paste same answer, hahaha